# Logic error, number passed by reference significantly higher

Tags: c++

Below I have pasted some code I wrote. The problem I am having is when turnmessage passes a number to found() (by reference) it is somehow increased drematically. For example if 3 is passed in I receive 3 million.

(the following is in the file projectmain.cpp)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

#include "project1.h"

using namespace std;

project1 game;

string str(int number){
    stringstream ss;
    ss << number;
    string result = ss.str();
    return result;
}

void project1::setNames(){
    string name;
    cout<< "Player one, enter your name: ";
    cin >> name;
    playerOneName = name;
    cout<< "Player two, enter your name: ";
    cin >> name;
}

void project1::resetBoard(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    RowOne[i] = str(i + 1);
    RowTwo[i] = str(i + 4);
    RowThree[i] = str(i + 7);
    }
    int used[] = {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1};
    turn = 1;
}

void project1::printBoard(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        cout << " | " << RowOne[i] << " | ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        cout << " | " << RowTwo[i] << " | ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        cout << " | " << RowThree[i] << " | ";
    }
    cout << endl;

}

string project1::PlayerOneName(){
    return playerOneName;
}

string project1::PlayerTwoName(){
    return playerTwoName;
}

bool project1::found(int& number){
    cout << " your number after pass: " << number;
    int i = 0;
    bool found = false;
    while(i < 9 && found == false){
        cout << used[i];
    if(used[i] == number)
        found = true;
    i++;
    }
    return found;
}

void project1::turnmessage(){
    int number = -1;
    bool found;
    do{
    if(turn == 1)
        cout << PlayerOneName();
        else
        cout <<PlayerTwoName();
    cout << " it's your turn!" << endl << "Enter the number you wish to use: ";
    cin >> number;
    number--;
    bool found = game.found(number);
    if (found == true)
        cout << "Sorry, that has already been used. Please try again.";
    }while(found == true);

}


int main(){
    game.setNames();
    game.resetBoard();
    game.printBoard();
    game.turnmessage();
return 0;   
}
```

(the following is in the file project1.h)

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>


using namespace std;

class project1{

public:
    void setNames();
    void resetBoard();
    void printBoard();
    void turnmessage();
    string PlayerOneName();
    string PlayerTwoName();
    bool found(int&);

private:
    int playerOneScore;
    int playerTwoScore;
    string playerOneName;
    string playerTwoName;
    string RowOne[3];
    string RowTwo[3];
    string RowThree[3];
    int used[9];
    int turn;

};
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the issue is here, in `resetBoard`:

```
int used[] = {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1};
```

This creates a local variable called `used` that's equal to the array of -1's, rather than changing the `used` data member to hold all -1's.  To fix this, try replacing this code with the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    used[i] = -1;
}
```

There might be other issues there, but this is certainly suspicious.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

`number` is not being changed to some large value in `project1::found` it is your output from this `std::cout` that is confusing you:

```
while(i < 9 && found == false){
    cout << used[i];
```

if you change it to this, it will be obvious what is going on:

```
while(i < 9 && found == false){
    cout << std::endl << used[i];
            ^^^^^^^^^
```

of you could add an `std::endl` here as well:

```
cout << " your number after pass: " << number << std::endl ;
```